# How to predict the sky's appearance?

Tags: weather

Sometimes it happens that the sky has a special color, e.g. lila in this [image](https://pics.craiyon.com/2023-07-15/7eafd9d4371f4459ab887bf2b955ecf8.webp) or orange in [this](https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/beautiful-sky_8327-258.jpg?w=1800&t=st=1704962930%7Eexp=1704963530%7Ehmac=2bbef38a2f9757f7c6ecf7a6f61bd8a25220265df2adce4ff54aa1d3277f79f5).

I would like to take the chance to take some pictures of it from special places (to get a beautiful view). These special places are sometimes more than one hour away. The time window for the special appearance is shorter than the travel time window. 
I know of no other way than observing the sky and, in case its appearance is considered special (colorful, unusual), get to the place I would take the picture from as soon as possible.

- Are there any indicators that the sky will have a special color - much earlier than seeing it?
- Are there any apps or websites which will give a probability for the appearance at the given day in advance?

Comment: Don't forget that photos can be enhance to increase the saturation.  You first link could well have been.  The 2nd seems more realistic.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would be better on photography.se, or even earth science - but I've done enough hikes for sunrise photography to consider it on-topic here

Comment: Worth reading https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/111974/3011

Comment: It's probably worth noting that when you take a photo of a sunset, the color of the photo will almost certainly be different from the actual color of the sunset. A beautiful sunset may or may not make a beautiful photo. You should probably practice by taking some photos of ordinary sunsets in order to get an idea of how the photo will differ from the real thing, and figure out how to take the best photo.

Comment: Just want to add another variable, not strictly on topic:  your eyes.   After a cararact operation, the sky looked very different to me:  not only brighter, but more violet.  Much more beautiful!  Same with some flowers.

Comment: @ab2 probably knows this, but it's because the artifical lens used in cataract operations passes more UV and deep blue than the natural original

Comment: @Chris H  Yes!  Doc kept urging me to get cataract operation because of driving at night (at that time, I never drove anyway)  and because I would see the tennis ball more clearly (but the tennis ball is intrinsically fuzzy!)   NOT compelling reasons!  If he had just said the sky will be more beautiful because of enhanced UV and blue transmission, I would have jumped at the operation instead of delaying for years and finally getting it to shut him up!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Time, direction, and location

These colours are characteristic of the time around sunrise and sunset, facing towards the sun.  So first you have to consider when, and at what angle, the sun will rise or set.  A site like [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/uk/bristol) (link is to my city) will calculate both the time and the bearing.

Obviously for sunrise you want a clear view to the east(ish), and for sunset, to the west(ish).  Both of these are much closer to the equator in winter, and to the poles in summer, so your sunrise direction varies with the season - from NNE in summer to SSE in winter, for northern mid latitudes.  Winter can give better shots in many locations, because of the lower humidity - unless a hazy effect is what you're looking for.

Sunrise often has clearer skies, as the temperature, humidity (affecting cloud cover) and level of pollution drop overnight.  Some mountainous regions get afternoon thunderstorms and the clouds from those don't dissipate fast.  On the other hand, you can look at the sky an hour or so before sunset and have an idea what the conditions will be like; for sunrise, you'll need to look at the forecast the night before, or get up very early.

During the day, you can scout a location's views in that direction at that time, to make sure there's nothing annoying in shot.  Google Street View is useful not just for locations you can drive to, but also for popular viewpoints.  So if you can't scout the location yourself, that may help.

Then aim to get there half an hour before sunset or an hour before sunrise.  The best colours are usually when the sun is below the horizon.  And don't forget that from high ground (with respect to the sunward terrain)  the horizon is lower, making the sun appear higher.

### Weather

Obviously you don't want heavy cloud.  Broken or scattered cloud adds interest to the shot compared to clear skies (in your second example the clouds are lit from blow by the sun passing through a thick layer of atmosphere).  For the latter you probably want an interesting horizon line and for the sun to be well below it (as in your first example).

You should look at the weather forecast for somewhere around 50km east of your viewpoint at sunrise, the same distance west at sunset, in addition to where you'll be.  This should be similar, but in mountainous terrain often isn't.

The weather can change fast though, as you'll see from the example I give below.

### Other features

A crescent moon (you won't get a full moon as that's opposite the sun in the sky) or a planet (Venus is the brightest star-like point of light in the sky) can add interest,  Various tools can tell you what will be visible where and when.  [Sky Map](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.stardroid&hl=en_GB&gl=US) for Android is what I use as it's free and simple.  The location doesn't matter much within an hour's drive, but the time is important.

### Examples

It's not my most colourful sunrise/set shot, but I have it here, well enough located in space and time to use it.

[image: Pen y Fan sunrise]

I shot this panorama at approximately (I don't have the metadata here, but the hike is on Strava) 0725 on 15 November 2021, at [Pen y Fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pen_y_Fan).  The hike up was in drizzle and light rain, but the cloud lifted just in time.  There was even a rainbow but it didn't make the panorama.  Timeanddate.com [tells me](https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/@12541296?month=11&year=2021) that the sun rose at 0733 on a bearing of 120° (near enough ESE) - a few minutes after this shot, but it's above the apparent horizon. It's pretty much horizontal in the shot, so I was holding the camera pretty much horizontal There's a lake visible in the distance, the southern tip of which is on 72°.  The best colours reach about half way to that from the sun, so around 45--50°.  That means that - in this case - you need to consider the view from ENE to SSE.  And for your purposes although this is the highest peak in the area, it might not be the best choice because Cribyn and Waun Rydd aren't that much lower and are sunwards.

With the sun above the hills, I'm getting some lens flare in this shot.  For colours, shooting before the sun came over the other hills would have been better.

A lot of this is rather nicely automated by [The Photographer's Ephemeris](https://app.photoephemeris.com/) - this screenshot shows a few features for the location and date of my example shot.
[image]

This is a sunset, over the [Nicoya Peninsula in Costa Rica, January 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicoya_Peninsula) (Wikipedia, where there's a full-resolution version of my photo).  The colours are as shot, but I used high dynamic range (HDR) techniques to get detail in both the foreground and the sky - the beach ans bushes were pretty dark, not surprisingly as it was about an hour after the nominal time of sunset.  I was facing almost due west.  Sunsets shot in the mountains a couple of days earlier, at a very similar time of day were considerably darker and redder, so timing is important.

[image: Sunset over Nicoya]

One final set of examples.  These were shot on Kodachrome 64 slide film in February 1994, from the top of Mount Sinai at sunrise, and scanned several years later - so I don't have metadata.  I used a rock for a tripod, and when I started the sequence of 10 images it was too dark to focus.  By the third of the images I selected here, when the sun was starting to show, the colours were washing out.  That's nominal sunrise, about 06:20, with the middle image 20-30 minutes before that, and the left one another 10-20 minutes before that.  So start setting up around an hour before sunrise by torchlight, then relax and let your eyes adjust.

[image]

Comment: The reason I have that example here is that it's my desktop background

Comment: There are actually websites/apps that supposedly predict the quality of the sunrise/sunset.  In addition there are tools for visualizing the location of the sun/moon at any date/time.  For the latter tools I have used them to predict not only when the moon would set just after the sun had risen, but also that the moon was setting directly down the center of a canyon (which turns out to be about 7AM in winter, in typically less than 20F temps. So setting up on site by 6:30) . These tools also tie into various maps, so you can see if the sun/moon are occulted by terrain.

Comment: @PeterM Sky Map will do location predictions (the option is called "Time 
Travel").  While I tend to plan stuff on my desktop, I'm happy enough to use that on my phone.  But of course it doesn't tie into maps.  So perhaps you'd like to add an answer with some of those options if you're familiar with any of them

Comment: I think that your answer covers all the points.  All I can add is some links, and I don't want to be accused of shilling.  But I've never used the apps that predict the sunrise/sunset quality - I only know that they exist.  The main (desktop) site I use is [The Photographer's Ephemeris](https://photoephemeris.com) (which also has great tools for predicting eclipses), as well as same timeanddate site that you use.

Comment: Where's also nearby natural disasters (eg smoke from wildfires) to keep in mind, not only because of their effects (haziness, colors) but also because of the danger.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas,truehhowever volcanic eruptions [can enhance sunsets](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/article/110617-volcano-eruption-ash-sunsets-chile-science-puyehue-volcanic) (National Geographic)

Comment: Right I wasn't trying to indicate that the natural disaster or event would necessarily _negatively_ affect the view, but that it would affect it in general, and one should be aware of such things for safety/planning reasons as well.